# Java Servlet Context and Session level variables

Tags: java, multithreading, servlets

I have experimented the inconsistency when multiple threads access/modify context variables but could not produce the same behaviour at session level. For example calling session.setAttribute("something") method within the service method does not cause race-condition when two requests (which means two threads) for same sessionid come in. Is it because Tomcat provides thread safety for session variables or I have got in completely wrong?

Comment: I doubt very much that tomcat provides any thready safety.

How are you testing accessing session attributes in a multithreaded way?  I know that using random numbers isn't the best way of testing something but when I test multithread issues I always sleep my threads for a randon amount of time (usually a few seconds) prior to calling the code in question.  Just a thought.

Comment: Not a great way, wrote a small program that is sending same session id. I cannot seem to find any resources saying thread safety of session variables is developer's responsibility but all of the discussions do advise for application level variables though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Servlet spec ver 3.0 explicitly states that access to session keys is thread-safe, in section 7.7.1.
However, access to elements stored under these keys isn't thread-safe. Thread safety in this case must be ensured by application developer.

*7.7.1 Threading Issues
      Multiple servlets executing request threads may have active access to the same
      session object at the same time. The container must ensure that manipulation of
      internal data structures representing the session attributes is performed in a thread
      safe manner. The Developer has the responsibility for thread safe access to the
      attribute objects themselves. This will protect the attribute collection inside the
      HttpSession object from concurrent access, eliminating the opportunity for an
      application to cause that collection to become corrupted.*

Sample code to illustrate this:

```
HttpSession session;
List items;
session.put("cart", items); // thread1 writes cart reference to session, this is thread-safe
...
items = session.get("cart"); // thread1 reads cart reference from session, this is thread-safe
items.get(0); // access to elements of application collection is *not* thread-safe, you must use explicit synchronization here.
```

I believe what is meant here by "thread safe manner" is that `HttpSession` access methods are guaranteed to be thread-safe, but all access to elements stored in session **by methods of these elements** is not guaranteed to be thread-safe.

Comment: Thanks for your response Victor, it seems as this "The container must ensure that manipulation of internal data structures representing the session attributes is performed in a thread safe manner" does answer my question but what you mentioned in the start goes against it.

Comment: @Victor, Thank you very much, if that is the case then it explains why I was not getting race condition when used session.setAttribute("key", "value");

Comment: @Victor I am assuming the same is NOT true for setting and getting application level variables?

Comment: +1 for the distinction between the attribute map itself and the values therein. Everone knows it and no-one realizes it when working with "thread-safe" maps :)

Answer (score 1):

After a reading a bit (amongst others [this bug fix](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=47930)) I do get the strong impression that sessions are thread-safe, or should be.

Answer (score 1):

you know all context variables are thread unsafe, except local, so if you are trying to access/modify this context variables use locks, in java it is `synchronized` objects, for more info read **Head First Servlets & JSP - Chapter 5**. Good luck!